# Error handling in SQL and bypassing errors

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm querying from a linked server that is returning the following error message. The query results look fine but I'm unable to run an INSERT statement using the code because of this. Is there a way to bypass the error and execute the stored procedure anyway. Changing the table design in the data source is not an option.

> OLE DB provider 'MSDASQL' for linked server 'ServerName' returned data
> that does not match expected data length for column
> '[ServerName]..[SQLUser].[STUSER].USERID'. The (maximum) expected data
> length is 4, while the returned data length is 5.

Comment: What ODBC driver are you using through MSDASQL? Also the normal workaround for data type issues in linked server is to use a passthrough query with OPENQUERY and perform a type conversion in the target system's SQL dialect.

Comment: The driver is InterSystems ODBC. I'm not familiar with OPENQUERY but will look into it.